# Azure Functions in visual studio missing service bus topic trigger

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I have no idea what is going on...I have tried everything I can think of.
complete uninstall and reinstall, made sure that all .net verions are installed.
I even created a brand new VM with a fresh install of VS and it does the same thing.

I am trying to create a Azure function for a Service Bus Topic Trigger per a tutorial I am following.
In the tutorial it gets to a point where it shows this:

[image]

Then I looked it up in the current Microsoft online docs here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs#check-your-tools-version

And it shows this:
[image]

I follow the steps exactly and all I am showing is this:
[image]

Service bus topic and queue triggers (along with a lot of other stuff) is simply not there.

I am trying to get a proof of concept done over the weekend and have hit a brick wall.

Comment: Are you selecting V2 / .net standard runtime?

Comment: You mean under target framework?  If so I am choosing .NET Standard 2.0 yes...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions V2 (.NET Standard 2.0) are still in beta, so they only support a limited set of templates at the moment.

Service Bus trigger is being moved into a separate NuGet package, and this work is not completed yet.

For now, you should stick to Functions V1 (Full .NET Framework 4.7) in order to use Service Bus triggers. Select it while creating your Function App project:

[image]

See [Azure Functions runtime 2.0 known issues](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Azure-Functions-runtime-2.0-known-issues).

Comment: Wow...I have been staring at that for the past 3 hours and did NOT notice that it was a selection with 2.0 and 1.0 on it.  Thank you for the push....

Comment: @JoeRuder Welcome! Added a screenshot just in case.